# How to create a shell command supporting Ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, command

I'm creating a gem in which I would like to be able to make a shell command performing a function in the gem. In a more simple context, I need to create a shell script that performs a Ruby function with options when the shell command is triggered. What is a easiest way to do this?

For example:

```
$ cow moo
```

would take a cow gem with a script for the cow command and perform the 'moo' function in the Ruby gem.

If I could, I would also like support for common 'options' formatting in the shell:

```
$ cow -t moo
```

Which the above example would take an option and apply a script in Ruby to handle it (in this example `-t` would print 'moo' twice).

If anyone could help we with this it would be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using http://visionmedia.github.com/commander/? Never used it before. But it's a gem that makes developing commandline apps easier :) Does the heavy lifting for you.

There is a bunch more over here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers

Comment: No, as said I have no experience with them. But I would assume its possible. Perhaps check the sourcecode of the gem and see how they write tests to test the framework.

Comment: @Beakr, you can build and install your gem without pushing it to rubygems, or just use Bundler. Read my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a regular executable Ruby file named `cow` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'cow'

Cow.say ARGV.first
```

Note the first line, which is the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). It tells your shell which program to use in order to interpret the script. This allows the user to simply call `cow` instead of `ruby $(which cow)`.

Put your script in the `bin` directory:

```
cow/
  bin/
    cow  <- your executable file
  lib/
    cow.rb
    cow/
      say.rb
  cow.gemspec
```

Now, all you need to do is put that in your gem specification:

```
Gem::Specification.new 'cow' do |gem|
  gem.executables = %w(bin/cow)
end
```

During installation, Rubygems will install your gem's binaries somewhere in the user's path, ensuring they can be found.

As for option parsing, the standard library includes [`optparse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html), but there are also [many gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers) available.

I created [my own option parser, called Acclaim](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/acclaim), which I use in my own utilities. Here's a sample:

```
class Cow::Command < Acclaim::Command
  option :all_caps, '-A', '--all-caps'

  when_called do |options, args|
    text = args.first.to_s
    text.upcase! if options.all_caps?
    Cow.say text
  end
end
```

In order to test your application, you can simply execute your script:

```
$ pwd
~/projects/cow
$ ./bin/cow moo
# output here...
```

However, this requires that you build your gem from the specification and install it locally every time you want to test your changes:

```
ruby -I ./lib -r cow -e 'puts Cow.version'
0.0.1
gem build cow.gemspec && gem install cow-0.0.1.gem
```

[Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) makes life easier by inserting your code into the load path automatically. You just have to run your executable through Bundler:

```
$ bundle exec ./bin/cow moo
# output here...
```